# Proving convergence of a sequence through a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let ($x_n$)$\rightarrow$x and let $p(x)$ be a polynomial.

(a) Show $p(x_n)$$\rightarrow$$p(x)$.

(b) Find an example of a function $f(x)$ and a convergent sequence ($x_n$)$\rightarrow$x where the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges, but not to $f(x)$.

For part (a) Is it enough to say that p($x_n$) is continuous at x because polynomials are continuous at all points, so the limit as $x_n$$\rightarrow$x of p($x_n$)=p(x) ?

For part (b) I'm having trouble seeing how this is possible.

Comment: For (b), consider $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}.$ $f(0)$ is not defined, but, $1/n\to0$ and $ n\sin (1/n) \to 1$.

Comment: For (a) using continuity of polynomials is sooner.

Comment: Or let $f: x \mapsto 1/x : ]0, \infty[ \to \mathbb{R}$ and $x_{n} := 1/n$ for all $n \geq 1$.

Comment: For part a, you just need to prove that sums and products of continuous functions are continuous. That's the beauty of polynomials: they're built up only by algebraic operations.

Comment: @Chilango so if I prove that the sums and products of continuous functions are continuous, then I know that the limit of p($x_n$) exists for all $x_n$? can you explain your idea please? thank you!

Comment: Is it enough to say that p($x_n$) is continuous at x because polynomials are continuous at all points, so the limit as $x_n$$\rightarrow$x of p($x_n$)=p(x) ?

Comment: That should be enough, yes Laura.

Answer (score 1):

For part b, all we need is a noncontinuous function, since continuity is what grants us that property.  Here's a simple one:

Define $f(x)=1$  if $x\ne 0$  and $f(0)=0$.  Then look at $x_n=\frac 1 n$.  Clearly $x_n\to 0$,  but $f(x_n)=1$ for all $x_n$,  hence $f(x_n)\to 1\ne f(0)$